# Erro na geração do objeto de classe

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private ArrayList Clientes (JSONObject jObect) {

    Log.e("Lis: ", jObect.toString());
    /* 
        A linha acima impime
        E/Lis:: {"clientes":[{"idClientesT":"1","tipo":"s","nome":"Carlos"},{"idClientesT":"2","tipo":"s","nome":"Rogério"}]}
     */

    ArrayList jArray = new ArrayList();

    try {

        // Transforma a jSon de resposta em um objjeo de Classe
        for (int i = 0; i < jObect.length(); i++) {

            int id =  jObect.getInt("idClientesT");
            String tipo = jObect.getString("tipo");
            String nome = jObect.getString("nome");

            Clientes cliente = new Clientes(id, tipo, nome);

            jArray.add(cliente);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro no parsing doo objeto " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;

}
```

Que me retorna um `ArrayList` de objetos da classe clientes que tem o atributo identificador, `idClientesT`, comodo tipo **int**

Acontece que na geração do objeto da classe:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jObect.length(); i++) {
        int id =  jObect.getInt("idClientesT");
```

Está dando erro:

Eis a classe:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes;

public class Clientes {
    private int idClientesT;
    private String tipo;
    private String nome;

    public Clientes(int idClientesT, String tipo, String nome) {
        this.idClientesT = idClientesT;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdClientesT() {
        return idClientesT;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Como ficaria essa parte,

```
int id =  jObect.getInt("idClientesT");
```

para que esse erro não ocorresse?

**Edição:**

Esse Json que estou chamando retorna uma string da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "clientes":
     [
        {"idClientesT":"1","tipo":"s","nome":"Carlos"},
        {"idClientesT":"2","tipo":"s","nome":"Rogério"}
     ]
}
```

Tentei da forma abaixo e também não funcionou:

```
private ArrayList Clientes (JSONObject jObect) {

    ArrayList jArray = new ArrayList();

    try {

        JSONObject jb = jObect.getJSONObject("Clientes");

        // Transforma a jSon de resposta em um objjeo de Classe
        for (int i = 0; i < jb.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jbi = jb.getJSONObject(i);
            int id =  Integer.parseInt(jb.getString("idClientesT"));
            //int id =  jObect.getInt("idClientesT");
            String tipo = jb.getString("tipo");
            String nome = jb.getString("nome");

            Clientes cliente = new Clientes(id, tipo, nome);

            jArray.add(cliente);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro no parsing doo objeto " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;

}
```

Comment: Tranquilo Andrei. Mas mesmo assim quero te agradecer pelo esforço. Se puder, coloquei  outra pergunta pois a sua resposta me deu um norte, uma direção. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352304/falha-na-adi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-objetos-de-classe-ao-array-list

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa converter a `string` que vem do json para `int`.

Não está especificado, mas pelo comentário no código, percebesse que o valor é uma `string`:

```
"idClientesT":"1" // <-- com aspas
```

Para isso, você pode fazer assim:

```
int id =  Integer.parseInt(jObect.getString("idClientesT"));
```

Se estivesse desta forma:

```
"idClientesT":1 // <-- sem aspas
```

Você poderia usar o `getInt()`

---

**Edição**

Antes de você fazer o loop no Objeto você precisa resgatar o array. Para depois fazer o loop e pegar todos os dados. Ficaria assim:

```
    try {
        JSONArray clientesLista = jObect.getJSONArray("clientes"); // aqui você faz o resgate da lista
        // Transforma a jSon de resposta em um objjeo de Classe
        for (int i = 0; i < clientesLista.length(); i++) {

            int id =  Integer.parseInt(clientesLista.get(i).getString("idClientesT"));
            String tipo = clientesLista.get(i).getString("tipo");
            String nome = clientesLista.get(i).getString("nome");

            Clientes cliente = new Clientes(id, tipo, nome);

            jArray.add(cliente);

      } // <-- estava faltando fechar o loop

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro no parsing doo objeto " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: rapaz, olhando um erro descobri outro. será preciso colocar índices no for. Tipo: String tipo = jObect.get(i).getString("tipo");. Mas não está funcionando. Como fazer?

Comment: ok. Sem querer ser chato, mas já sendo, perceba por favor que o array é um arrray de json chamado Clientes.

Comment: @CarlosRocha dá uma olhada, isso deve resolver.

Comment: @CarlosRocha fiz outra edição, tinha faltado uma informação

Comment: @CarlosRocha deu certo? Não esquece de aprovar por favor!

Comment: Então, desculpe  demora, não funcionou. Esse webservice que estou chamando retorna uma string da seguinte forma: {"clientes":[{"idClientesT":"1","tipo":"s","nome":"Carlos"},{"idClientesT":"2","tipo":"s","nome":"Rogério"}]}. Logo temos um array de objetos. Então o get(i), com a letra i do iterator dento não funcionou

Comment: por favor, cancelem a edição que fiz acidentalmente no post do colega @Andrei Coelho

Comment: @CarlosRocha mas você criou o JSONArray?

Comment: sim, criei o Json, ele vem de outra função. como eu coloquei na pergunta tem até uma log.e dele.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, agradecendo ao esforço do colega Andrei que in felizmente apagou sua resposta, vou colocar aqui como ficou a solução e que ela possa ajudar outros colegas.

```
private ArrayList<Clientes> Clientes (JSONObject jObect) {
   // Cria o Array List de Clientes
    ArrayList<Clientes> aCli = null;

    try {

        aCli = new ArrayList<>();
        //Pega o primeiro índice do Array de Objetos, no caso, o array Clientes
        JSONArray clientesLista = jObect.getJSONArray("clientes"); // aqui você faz o resgate da lista

        // Transforma a JSONArray de resposta em um Array de objjeo da Classe Clientes
        for (int i = 0; i < clientesLista.length(); i++) {
            //Pega cada íncide do array e atribui a uma variável
            JSONObject jSobj = clientesLista.getJSONObject(i);
            //Indetifica os campos do objeto
            int id =  Integer.parseInt(jSobj.getString("idClientesT"));
            //int id =  jSobj.getInt("idClientesT");
            String tipo = jSobj.getString("tipo");
            String nome = jSobj.getString("nome");
           //popula o objeto da classe de clientes
            Clientes cliente = new Clientes(id, tipo, nome);
            //Adiciona o objeto de Classe criado ào Array de Clientes
            aCli.add(cliente);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro no parsing doo objeto " + e.toString());
    }
    //Retorno o array de Clientes.
    return aCli;

}
```

Comment: Restaurei a minha resposta.